# org mode export a backslash to latex and html

Tags: html, latex, org-mode

In Emacs 24.5 using org mode 20150706 I want to export a line like:

```
* foo\bar
```

to LaTeX as:

```
\item foo\textbackslash{}bar
```

and to HTML as

```
<li>foo\bar
</li>
```

I get the html I want, but the LaTeX is

```
\item foo\bar
```

which wrongly it invokes the "\bar" command.

Using the verbatim format coding:

```
* foo=\=bar
```

produces wrong results, where the LaTeX is

```
\item foo=$\backslash$=bar
```

and the html is

```
<li>foo=\=bar
</li>
```

How should I get the desired effect?

Answer (score 2):

Using verbatim coding is correct, but it is incorrectly applied. Instead of only coding the backslash, code the whole expression:

```
* =foo\bar=
```

Then the LaTeX is

```
\item \texttt{foo\textbackslash{}bar}
```

and the HTML is

```
<li><code>foo\bar</code>
</li>
```